# Discord.NET better way of comparing roles

Tags: c#, warnings, bots, discord, discord.net

So in my Discord bot, I am creating a full moderation system where users with appropriate privileges may hand out warnings to other users, these will be recorded, once 3 warnings are hit, the user is muted for a set time, this can occur 5 times for which they are muted for longer periods of time, after the fifth mute when the user reaches 3 more warnings, they are banned permanently. So I have pretty much made the whole thing which was no issue with a history viewer of users etc, but the problem I am having is with comparing roles. I have found a solution that I am not sure if it works properly in the long run, but was the only method I could think of. I want it to not allow users to warn those with higher ranks than themselves. This is the code I have for it:

```
public class Warn : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("Warn")]
        public async Task WarnMain([Remainder, Summary("Warn a user for a reason.")] IGuildUser user, string warnInfo)
        {
            var userRole = -1;
            var victimRole = -1;
            var counter = 0;
            foreach(var role in Context.Guild.Roles)
            {
                if (Context.Guild.GetUser(Context.User.Id).Roles.Contains(role) && userRole == -1)
                {
                    userRole = counter;
                }
                if (Context.Guild.GetUser(user.Id).Roles.Contains(role) && victimRole == -1)
                {
                    victimRole = counter;
                }
            }
            if (userRole < victimRole)
            // blah blah
        }
    }
```

If you know of a better way or more efficient way of doing this, please share, would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, you can do `user.RoleIds.Count` to get the amount of roles the user has. Though that includes the `@everyone` role. You can check up the `IGuildUser.RoleIds` property here: https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.IGuildUser.html#Discord_IGuildUser_RoleIds

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would like to point out that discord.py has their own method of comparing between permissions. You could try to run their python script in your C# code, or 'translate' it from python into C#.
 You can check out their source code for comparing between permissions [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/f57ec81eec00f45f7aab2c25db67973239a47a31/discord/permissions.py).

For me personally, since my bot is not really made for moderation, I took the lazy way out and made a simple function that compares permissions using nested if-else statements.

```
private static bool PermissionComparison(GuildPermissions targetGuildPerms, GuildPermissions userGuildPerms)
{
    //True if the target has a higher role.
    bool targetHasHigherPerms = false;
    //If the user is not admin but target is.
    if(!userGuildPerms.Administrator && targetGuildPerms.Administrator) {
        //The target has higher permission than the user.
        targetHasHigherPerms = true;
    } else if(!userGuildPerms.ManageGuild && targetGuildPerms.ManageGuild) {
        targetHasHigherPerms = true;
    } else if(!userGuildPerms.ManageChannels && targetGuildPerms.ManageChannels) {
        targetHasHigherPerms = true;
    } else if(!userGuildPerms.BanMembers && targetGuildPerms.BanMembers) {
        targetHasHigherPerms = true;
    } else if(!userGuildPerms.KickMembers && targetGuildPerms.KickMembers) {
        targetHasHigherPerms = true;
    }

    return targetHasHigherPerms;
}
```

I would personally suggest using other methods instead if they seem better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the way I did it is the only way to actually compare roles as far as I can tell. Spent the last 4 hours looking for alternatives but did not come across anything.

My method is simply going through each role and comparing, I believe the API already sorts the roles from highest first to lowest last. You can then use a counter to compare the numbers at which the highest role is found that is assigned the the user.

Comparing permissions doesn't always work, especially in my case, therefore I could not use that method either. This seems to work best for me. If anyone has anything better feel free to share, I'd love to see how I can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you cast the user to a SocketGuilderUser then you can compare the Hierarchy property.
Its basically the same thing you are already doing just avoids looping through the roles.